# Who/what determines the format of an image?

Tags: image, format

Today I put together a presentation and grabbed a few graphics off the web.  As I organized the image files in their respective folder, it struck me--why are there different image formats and what determines the format an image is in?

I'm sure there are many factors, but just merely browsing the internet and grabbing images from one site or another I'll find many JPEG, PNG, static GIF files and more.  Does one format work better than another with certain languages?  Or could it be solely dependent on the source and age of the file?

Answer (score 2):

The format of an image depends on how said image was created. Almost every language can handle I/O with files, and the format wouldn't really matter from language to language. The creator of the file determines what format it is in.

Comment: Is there a reason this hasn't been standardized?  Or has the interoperability of image types likely made that a moot effort?